# MBProgressHUD is not working

Tags: iphone

the RootViewController in my NavigationController has a UIButton. When clicking this Button some data are loading from a server and finally a new View comes up. This can take some seconds, so i want to display the MBProgressHUD during that time to show the user what's going on. But it does not work.

loading the data and show the HUD, all happens in my prepareForSegue-Method and it looks like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAllPoints"])
     {
         HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
         HUD.labelText = @"Loading data";
         HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Please wait...";
         HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
         [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

         [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(prepareJSONData:) 
              onTarget:self withObject:        
         [self getJSONData] animated:YES];

         [self prepareJSONData:[self getJSONData]];
         [segue.destinationViewController setPoints:pointsArray];
    }

}
```

and nothing is happen, so wehre is the mistake? What is wrong there?

EDIT:
Here are the Methods getJSON and prepareJSONData :

```
-(NSData *)getJSONData
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.de/example.php"];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  [request setURL:url];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

  NSError *error;
  NSURLResponse *response;

  NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

return urlData;
}


-(void)prepareJSONData:(NSData *)jsonData
{
  NSError *error;

  NSDictionary *wholeDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

  allWutpunkteArray = [wholeDict objectForKey:@"points"];

 }
```

Comment: Does `[HUD show:YES]` work (instead of `showWhileExecuting`) ?

Comment: no, it does not work. i need the showWhileExecuting-Method, and i also tried to implement both and nothig is working

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

         if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAllPoints"])
         {
             HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
             HUD.labelText = @"Loading data";
             HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Please wait...";
             HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
             [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
             [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(prepareJSONData:[self getJSONData]) 
                  onTarget:self withObject:        
             nil animated:YES];
             [segue.destinationViewController setPoints:pointsArray];
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: this is not a solution, i need to call both methods (prepareJSONData: and getJSONData) within the @selector. Why is it not working? Who can help me??

Comment: then can you show the both the implementation of prepareJSONData and getJSONData?

Comment: i dun understand. your prepareJSONData calls the getJSONData? Then why you need to call both at the same time? call one of them.. it will automatically will call the other..

Comment: Thank you for your answers so far. the prepareJSONData-Method needs a parameter and this is [self getJSONData]. i will edit my Code above to show you both Methods.

Comment: I understand now.. you are thinking of how to pass the parameter to the showWhileExecuting? Am i right? You don't need to do that. You just need to pass it as prepareJSONData:. That is enu..

Comment: Yes i'm thinking about how to pass the parameter, and you think it's enough when is type: `[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(prepareJSONData:) 
                  onTarget:self withObject:        
             nil animated:YES];` But how should the compiler know wich parameter to use? Anyway, this does not work.

Comment: another suggestion, instead of passing the json data. you can call NSData *jsondata = [self getJSONData] inside of passing the jsondat to the prepareJSONData and use that. in the HUD, use prepareJSONData instead of prepareJSONData:. hope this helps..

Comment: the edited solution causes an error "Expected ')'" so a bracket is missing, i will try your another suggestion.

Comment: i tried your suggestion, the result is: the HUD appears too late and disapears too early. And the SecondViewController that appears has incomplete data. Now i have a chaos app. i think about to throw all the HUD stuff out of the window, and simply use an ActivityIndicator to indicate a progress, this works but also appears too late and disapperas too early no matter where i put show or hide